# DynamoDB Query for users with expired IP addresses

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

So I have a DynamoDB database table which looks like this (exported to csv):

```
"email (S)","created_at (N)","firstName (S)","ip_addresses (L)","lastName (S)","updated_at (N)"
"name@email","1628546958.837838381","ddd","[  { ""M"" : {      ""expiration"" : { ""N"" : ""1628806158"" },      ""IP"" : { ""S"" : ""127.0.0.1"" }    }  }]","ddd","1628546958.837940533"
```

I want to be able to do a "query" not a "scan" for all of the IP's (attribute attached to users) which are expired. The time is stored in unix time.

Right now I'm scanning the entire table and looking through each user, one by one and then I loop through all of their IPs to see if they are expired or not. But I need to do this using a query, scans are expensive.

The table layout is like this:

primaryKey = email
attributes = firstName, lastName, ip_addresses (array of {} maps where each map has IP, and Expiration as two keys).

I have no idea how to do this using a query so I would greatly appreciate if anyone could show me how! :)

I'm currently running the scan using python and boto3 like this:

```
response = client.scan(
        TableName='users',
        Select='SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES',
        AttributesToGet=[
            'ip_addresses',
        ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the boto3 documentation, The Query operation finds items based on primary key values. You can query any table or secondary index that has a composite primary key (a partition key and a sort key).

Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression . To further refine the Query results, you can optionally provide a FilterExpression . A FilterExpression determines which items within the results should be returned to you. All of the other results are discarded.

So long story short, it will only work to fetch a particular row whose primary key you have mentioned while running query.

A Query operation always returns a result set. If no matching items are found, the result set will be empt

Comment: So how would I do this with my setup?